# Codeigniter include files

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to include a header in my application.I created a controllers `site` and defined a function `header` in it, which renders the data variables to `views/header.php`

However, when i try to access `myUrl/site/header` all varialble work fine but when i create another function in site controller `index` and include `views/header` in that, and i run `site/index` then i get Undefined variable notices in the header.

Any Idea??

`class site extends CI_Controller {
function header()
{`

`$data =array('name'=>'foo');`

`$this->load->view('includes/header',$data); 
}`

`function index()
{`

`$this->load->view('includes/index');`

`}
}`

`INDEX.PHP`

`$this->load->view('includes/header');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it Solved!!!!

Wrote a new helper and returned the data from there, then passed the data to view  using load->view('includes/header',$data);

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep separate segments(e.g header, footer, navigation bar etc) of your Html pages to separate view files, I think it's better to do this in the following way

keep the contents you want to be header to a file name header.php(or anything else you like) to views folder. Suppose, the contents of the header.php is

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>This is title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
```

Another file named footer.php contains the following

```
</body>
</html>
```

Another file my_view.php in view folder that will hold the contents of that page. Sample contents are

```
<?php $this->load->view('header');?>
<h1>Welcome</h1>
<p>Main contents here</p>
<?php $this->load->view('footer');?>
```

Now, if you load the my_view from your controller function, the entire HTML page will be rendered.

```
function my_controller_function(){
    $this->load->view('my_view');
}
```

Comment: The problem is, there are dynamic variables in the header view, which are defined in header controller.These variables are problematic and gives undefined eror

Comment: I think you should try to refactor the code. What you want to do is not the normal behavior

Answer (score 0):

This is not the correct way of doing it. Basically i do it like Rafiqunnabi except i don't load views within views.

For e.g:

```
 public function index()
{
  $this->load->view('include/header');
  $this->load->view('home');
  $this->load->view('include/footer');
}
```

Comment: I am usin the above code, but it has problems with variables used in `include/header`